# How to locate largest directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell, directory

I am wanting to create a bash script that locates the directories over 500mb within a directory `foo`.

I have this command which finds the directories with foo in ascending size order.

```
du /foo/* | sort -n
```

The problem with this is it includes the size of the parent directory. So for example an output will be:

```
...
442790 /foo/bar/baz/qux
442800 /foo/bar/baz
442880 /foo/bar
```

I want the output to just show `/foo/bar/baz/qux`. As the parent directories are including `/foo/bar/baz/qux` in there own file size but in actual fact they are tiny folders when excluding `/foo/bar/baz/qux`.

---

Some pseudo code:

```
if the current directory is greater than 500mb then 
    check next directory is parent to current directory (i.e `/foo/bar/baz` is parent of `/foo/bar/baz/qux`) then 
        takeaway size of parent from current.
        if resulting size is greater than 500mb then
            return row
        else
            go to next row
    else
        go to next row
else
    go to next row
```

Comment: I'm from the mobile app now, but im sure there's a `find` option for doing exactly this. search over SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `find` and GNU `sort`:

```
find /some/dir -type d -exec du -hS {} + | sort -rh
```

`du -S` prints the size of a directory excluding subdirectories.

Comment: This is not what I want. For example if `/foo/bar/` contains lots of files thus making it big but there is a child directory within. It seems to ignore `/foo/bar` and return the child directory